# MultiValueDictKeyError in django

Tags: python, django

hi i am trying to make a sign up page in django -

my views.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'signup' in post:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/wall/signup')
    return render(request, 'wall/home_page.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        username = post['username']
        password = post['password']
        return success(request, username)
    return render(request, 'wall/signup.html')

def success(request, name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'home' in post:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/wall')
    return render(request, 'wall/success_page.html', {'name': name})
```

and my success_page.html-

```
<html>
    <body>
        Success {{ name }}
        <form id="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" name="home">
                Home
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when i m clicking 'home' button it is giving error -

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /wall/signup/

"'username'"
```

I think line - `username = post['username']` is giving this error

I dont know how to resolve it and I don't even know why i am getting this error.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<form>` tag in the `success_page.html` doesn't have an `action` attribute so then you click `Home` button the form is sent back to the `signup()` view.

You should change the `signup()` view to redirect to the success view instead of returning of the result of the `success()`:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        return redirect('signup_success', username)
```

Where the `signup_success` is the name of the url pointing to the `success()` view.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^success/(?P<name>\w+)/$', views.success, name='signup_success'),
    ...
)
```

Or, as alternative, add the `action` attribute to the `success_page.html`:

```
<form id="form" action="{% url 'signup_success' name %}" method="post">
```

Comment: Definitely go for the redirect. It's  a good habit to always redirect after a `POST` request.

Comment: but after clicking on 'home' shouldn't it redirect to '/wall'..??

Comment: Nope. You form has no `action` attribute so then you click "Home" browser send POST form to the same url from which the form was opened.  In your case this is the `/wall/signup` page. Look at the browser's location bar.

Comment: if i go with the first method then what changes must i do in my urls.py..??

Comment: Just add the `name="signup_success"` argument to the `url()` call.  See the updated answer.